# Удаленеи view по которому кликнул

Tags: textview, удаление

Как удалить тот view по TextView которого кликнул

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fields"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 
    <LinearLayout> <EditText../><EditText../><TextView../>   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout> <EditText../><EditText../><TextView../>  </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout> <EditText../><EditText../><TextView../>  </LinearLayout>
     ...
 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Пробовал так

```
       public View.OnClickListener removeField(View view,TextView img){
  LinearLayout rlayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fields);// это родитель для всех LinearLayout
// img, это картинка(вьюшка) по которой я кликаю
  return new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
   ViewParent pr = img.getParent();// по идее это родитель для набора
   rlayout.removeView((ViewGroup)pr);
}
};
}
```

Но так удаляет по порядку, снизу вверх